# iOS 14 - Application does not have an entry in the device settings

Tags: ipad, software-update, permission, development, ios

I develop an enterprise application and I updated my iPad Air to iOS 14 to test compatibility of app with this brand new iOS but after OS update I reinstalled the app and I saw that for the application I don't have an entry in the device set
Did anyone have the same problem?[image]

Comment: Are those really apps, or shortcuts to webpages?

Comment: These are really mobile apps developed with Xamarin Forms

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. “ Did anyone have the same problem?” is a yes or no question. If the existing answer doesn’t help could you refine what specifically you want to have happen? We might need to know a bit more or have you ask on Stack Overflow if this is about developing your own apps.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can get the apps to appear by simply quitting and reopening the Settings app.

On the iPad Air you can do that by double-clicking the Home button to get the app switch. Swipe upwards on the Settings app in order to quit it.

After opening the Settings app again, the list should be refreshed.

If this doesn't help, ensure that you can actually start the apps in question. I.e. tap them to run them.

Comment: I tried with closing settings app , reboot the iPad and reset all settings but no result.
It's not clear to me what you meant by "ensure that you can actually start the apps in question. I.e. tap them to run them" the the application opens and runs ok

Comment: Are you sure those apps have a settings bundle? You could possibly have updated these apps in the process, and newer versions of the apps might not have settings bundles.

Comment: It is possible those apps are xamarin forms apps and till now we have only the info.plist file and no settings.bundle files in the solutions

Comment: If they have no settings bundle, then why should it show it up? - So that seems to be the reason

Comment: Indeed you are right, thank you very much for your help, I added to iOS project the Settings.bundle file and now I have an app entry in device settings.
But a good question for which I need to find an answer is how it works till now and why if i deploy the application from Mac to tablet in debug mode via USB cable an app entry is created in device settings.

Comment: That's because the debugger has some settings in there...